# Adding a UIScrollView to subview does not scroll

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, subview, addsubview

I have a view controller with a button. When the button is pressed, I want to add a subview which contains a scrollview. Right now my code displays the subview and scrolls fine as long as I don't add the xib. When I add the xib to the scrollview, the xib appears in the subview but there is no longer any scrolling.

The main View Controller:

```
-(IBAction)startNewSearch:(id)sender {
    UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];

    UIView *myView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewSearch" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    [myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];
    [myScrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [myScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [myScrollView setPagingEnabled:NO];

    [myScrollView addSubview:myView];

    [self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
}
```

The NewSearch class is a UIView. It's xib is 320 wide by 600 high.

Comment: Nobody has an answer for this? OK... baring any light bulb moments, I will assume that adding a UIScrollView to a subview does not work. I have substituted this issue by pushing a separate view controller with a scrollview. Very similar to the TMZ app for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question exactly, but it may or may not be similar to something I did.

See if adding this will work:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {    
   [self.myScrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 600)];
}
```

Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for... I too am having issues with scrollview stuff. Good luck!

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just resolved a similar issue where a UIScrollView froze up on me. Your suggestion resolved the problem.

Comment: Fantastic! I'm glad it worked for you! Now if only I could figure out why mine is freezing up... haha

Comment: I was never able to really find the root of the problem. The solution to my other issue was to use the command "scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 960);" in the "-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated". Without this, it would just freeze the scroll. But why remains open.

Comment: Yeah, I really wish that line of code would solve my issue, but unfortunately it doesn't affect it in any way...  So the search for the answer continues... :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have same content size height as a frame height.
Try to use same frame size as your main view on your screen and content size of the scroll view should be bigger then height (in your case) or width (this depends on which scroll you  need horizontally or vertically).

For example

```
CGRect scrollFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [self.view bounds].size.height, self.view bounds].size.width);
UIScrollView *myScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame: scrollFrame];

...

[myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, **800**)];
```

As you see there is height of content size bigger then frame height of the your scroll view. So it can scroll horizontally.
Also see the [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) documentation.

Comment: First, sorry for getting back to this so late. I tried that. I actually had 890 for height. For some reason adding a scroll view as a subview just does not seem to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when I started using ios8. It turns out that touches were being trapped by something in the chain of view controllers. When I started using presentView Controller for the view controller containing the scrollview, then touches (and scrolling)started working again.